# Firefox plugin CPU usage

Tags: firefox, plugins, cpu-usage

I need to collect data on firefox CPU usage during web-development coding session and I'm wondering if it is possible to monitor CPU usage of particular firefox plugin.

Right now i'm using windows' perfmon.msc, but it will only allow me to monitor firefox process as a whole.

Do you know any tools that would allow me to get CPU data from a plugin? Is it possible at all ?

Comment: thinking about it, there should really be a firefox/mozilla API to instrument plugins, that would also help to identify resource hogs (bandwidth, CPU, RAM etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could analyze the CPU usage using [**Process Explorer**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). Right-click on the Firefox process and select properties. On the *Threads* tab you will see the different threads including add-ins such as Flash or Acrobat with their CPU usage listed.

EDIT: In fact, it should be possible to monitor threads with perfmon, too: Right-click to select *Add Counters...* and then choose *Threads* as performance object.

Comment: Perhaps you know if there's a way to collect data Process Explorer is displaying ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But you might want to give the other tools of the Sysinternals suite a try. In fact, it should be possible to monitor threads with perfmon, too: Right-click to select Add Counters and then choose Threads as performance object.

Comment: It's somewhat useful, but not completely - many addons consume CPU in the main Firefox thread.

Comment: This won't tell me what tab or JS library is running.  Or a new thing I 'found' today, called "service workers".  A firefox internal monitor is really what's required.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess your best option would be to test your plugin in a seperate Firefox process, but you're probably doing that anyway.

For real profiling you should use Firebug.  I'm not sure about it, but I think it is possible to run XUL apps inside of Firefox (without integrating it as a plugin).  If this is not an option then you could maybe separate out code that you suspect to be slow into a web page and profile it with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).  This would of course only work for stuff that is not interacting with the Mozilla core.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Firefox does have a built-in "Task-Manager" for a few years now. Just type *about:performance* in the URL. It shows Name, Type, Energy Impact and Memory of each tab and add-on.

If you want to dig deeper Shift + F5 opens the [performance tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Performance) where you can record e. g. opening a website and look into timings etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are some JS profilers which also profile extension JS, however they don't really help on finding problematic addons.

There was a feature on the concept design of Firefox 4, however it's dumped as FX4 is feature-frozen now. But I'm still after that feature and wish to follow any progress in that direction.

Here is a question to find more about it;
https://superuser.com/q/218733/46962

For CPU utilization, you can collect the data using MS Perfmon, which is a part of Windows, and also used for similar purposes, like collecting CPU performance & stats data on SQL server for optimization.

Comment: There's always Firefox 5 and 6; shame it was dropped just because of the feature freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Now in Firefox 94 there are such tools:

- `about:performance` can show you CPU (Energy Impact) and Memory usage for all tabs and addons.
- `about:memory` will allow you to make recordings of processes' resource usage statistics, then you can filter it knowing CPU-hungry process id, which you get from `htop` or `top` command. In the recorded snapshot you'll see extensions and their unique ids and can use it to identify and remove the extension.