# Measure performance of firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Is there a tool to measure the performance of my firefox extension. And is there a toll which part of my script takes lot of CPU?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665296/firefox-plugin-cpu-usage

Comment: @karthikrangaraj: I don't see any useful information in the question you linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a JavaScript profiler. Unfortunately, I don't know any good profilers for this. The usual recommendation would be Firebug but it doesn't work for add-ons (maybe with [Chromebug](http://blog.getfirebug.com/category/chromebug/) but I'm not sure about that). There is also [XUL profiler](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/xul-profiler-by-yoono/) which is outdated but might still work in newer Firefox versions (you can use [Add-on Compatibility Reporter](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/) to install and test incompatible add-ons). And there is [JavaScript Deobfuscator](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/javascript-deobfuscator/) which is meant for something different but can do some basic profiling as well. There you can adjust the filters to include only JavaScript files of your extension and see all the functions that are being called - along with the number of calls and the average execution time. This is sometimes good enough to identify the bottlenecks.